# NullPointerException in App.main when using NetLogo controlling API

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netlogo

I want to connect netbeans to netlogo. 
I have a class: NetLogoConnection 
I want to call the class when I click on OK btn in my GUI. 
The codes are as following:

```html
import org.nlogo.app.App;
public class NetLogoConnection {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    App.main(argv);
    try {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          App.app().open("C:/Users/fmar825/Desktop/fire.nlogo");
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }}});
     // App.app().command("set density 62");
     // App.app().command("random-seed 0");
     // App.app().command("setup");
      //App.app().command("repeat 50 [ go ]");
      //System.out.println(
//App.app().report("burned-trees"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And the code for calling the class with JButton is as following :

```html
private void okbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
 
        try {
           NetLogoConnection.main(new String[0] );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     
    


}
```

The code for calling the method of run is as following:

The error Message is a s following:

```html
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1289)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1282)
 at org.nlogo.awt.EventQueue$.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.scala:19)
 at org.nlogo.app.App$.main(App.scala:150)
 at org.nlogo.app.App.main(App.scala)
 at NetLogoConnection.main(NetLogoConnection.java:4)
 at User.okbtnActionPerformed(User.java:993)
 at User.access$1600(User.java:31)
 at User$19.actionPerformed(User.java:603)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.nlogo.window.RuntimeErrorDialog.suppressJavaExceptionDialogs(RuntimeErrorDialog.java:63)
 at org.nlogo.app.App.handle(App.scala:779)
 at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handle(Exceptions.scala:21)
 at org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$7.uncaughtException(App.scala:305)
 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(EventDispatchThread.java:223)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:215)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: `NetLogoConnection.main(argv);` ? where did you get that `argv`?

Comment: I do not want have the main class here, But when I remove the main class it will not successful. I run this code separately in a new project and it is successful and open netlogo from netbeans, but when I run t inside my application i see this error message. Here is the link for controling API:https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API

Comment: You might want to ask about this on the NetLogo developer Google group.

Comment: Looks to me like you're passing a null argv. Pass an empty array instead.

Comment: Sounds like netbeans is passing something to your main() command line when it runs the code, but when you run it stand-alone it is nulled out. If you need the optargs you should process and normalize them before passing them to your APIs.

Comment: I deleted the argv inside main method but I got error again. How I can pass empty array instead of a null argv.

Comment: I have an idea: If I execute the NetLogoConnection class in a seperate project it run and execute correctly. so how I can link the project consist of NetLogoConnection class  to my main project. Then i just can call that class from outside.

Comment: Sound like you need a NetBeans expert, rather than a NetLogo expert? I don't think any of us have used NetBeans.

Comment: note that this has also been asked at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/netlogo-devel/vrRp8mripU0/TkTghVkSyOoJ

Comment: I just edit the okbtnActionPerformed method and got new error. Moreover when I click on the ok btn the netlogo start to run but it stops and cannot open the netlogo IDE.